# How to use an AirPort Express as an AirPlay device with a TP-Link router?

Tags: airport

I recently upgraded my router (TP-Link TL-WR1043N) so now my wireless network is broadcasting in 11b/g/n mixed mode, and my 1st generation AirPort Express is having trouble joining the network.

I have done a factory reset several times, and each time everything seems to work fine but then when the APE tries to reset, AirPort Utility bombs with the message

> AirPort Utility was unable to find your AirPort wireless device after restarting.

I'd love to keep this working just as an AirPlay device.

UPDATE: I tried resetting the wireless network to use 11bg mode, but got the same result. So I'm guessing the thing has just crapped out coincidentally at the same time I made the change to my network. Oh well!

Comment: What kind of security settings are you using? none, WEP, WPA, 802.1x? Which Wi-Fi standard is being configured? 802.11b or 802.11g?

Comment: What are you using to configure the APE (Mac, iPhone, ..)? Have you try connecting the Ethernet port of the APE to the router and then trying to configure it this way?

Comment: I am using WPA for the security and the network is in 802.11abgn mixed mode. I'm configuring the APE on a Mac using the Airport utility. The last few attempts I had it wired via Ethernet and got the same result. Thanks!

Comment: Your update makes it less clear there's a need to let people answer this. Feel free to edit it and provide an actual answer below if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same thing. I have three AirPort Expresses and it seems to me that my oldest one is not compatible with the new technology. The other two work fine. I can't update the firmware, so I guess I'm left with buying a new one. It took my whole system down.

Comment: hm, have you tried conecting the oldest one directly to your router (with pan) with the wireless settings to off?, it just might be able to send airplay

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to extend the wireless network! [Loud sound link!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RfkEmk6JgI)
and you shuld be able to use it perfectly as a repeater and airplay, this is how i use mine, however if your issue still presists, try conect it with a LAN cable, although this should not be needed!

Answer (score 0):

I have a TP-Link TL-WDR3600 and a first gen Airport Express. I was having the same problems until I set both configurations to use WPA2 Personal instead of WPA/WPA2 Personal. With that change, the Express now connects to the wireless network.